Whole House Water Filter System
I'd like to purchase a whole house water filtration system. The well water has a lot of iron (1000 parts per billion or ppb) and it has lead (1 ppb). I understand 1 ppb isn't bad at all, but I'd like to eliminate the lead (or reduce it) since we have little kids that bathe in the water and accidentally drink it, etc.

Since NSF 53 ensures reduction to 5 ppb of lead, does that mean that because I'm at 1 ppb lead, it won't do anything, or will it still reduce it by 99%.

Is there a whole house water system that will reduce the lead if I'm at 1 ppb and also reduce the iron?



1 ppb, one part per billion

Have you searched for water filters? The details such as what each filter can achieve is in the specs.

Yes I looked at the SDS, and they all say removes 99% lead < X ppb where X is somewhere between 2 and 15 but it doesn’t tell me if I have 1 ppb lead what happens.
